# Should I use "location" or "placement" in a job advertisement?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, difference

I'm writing a job advertisement and am wondering which word to use in the heading to describe where the workplace is. I've looked at many English job ads and found some with "location". My friend says that we should use "placement".

Am I right in thinking that "placement" is odd in this context (to me, it sounds more like something you would use for a workplace that you're "placed at" as part of your training), or is my friend right (that "placement" does work equally well)?

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey Haha, ok – thanks!

Comment: Oh gosh – was that me?? Who deleted your comment??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience *placement* is rarely used for physical location: only when we're talking about placing objects in some physical arrangement. Certainly not for the geographical location of a business.

Its main use is to do with placing people with an organisation: usually about interns or apprentices, or temporary assignments, rather than main employment; but it would certainly be misleading for "location" in this context.

Comment: Thank you! Nice to see that my intuition was spot on :)